# When doing tf.train.example, there is TypeError: 71 has type int, but expected one of: bytes

Tags: python, tensorflow

There is type error, but the type is bytes already. Please help me with it. Thanks.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "toTFRECORDS_1.py", line 29, in <module>
>       feature = {'train/image': _bytes_feature(img_data),
>    File "toTFRECORDS_1.py", line 10, in _bytes_feature
>       return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=value))
> TypeError: 71 has type int, but expected one of: bytes
> ```

The code is below. But I don't know where is wrong and I can't figure it out by myself.

```
def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=value))

images = os.listdir('D:\python_64\Training_Set')


train_filename = 'train.tfrecords'
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(train_filename) as tfrecord_writer: 
    for i in range(len(images)):
        # read in image data by tf
        img_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(os.path.join('D:\python_64\Training_Set',images[i]), 'rb').read()  # image data type is string
        # get width and height of image
        image_shape = plt.imread(os.path.join('D:\python_64\Training_Set',images[i])).shape
        width = image_shape[1]
        height = image_shape[0]

        # create features
        feature = {'train/image': _bytes_feature(img_data),
                       'train/label': _int64_feature(i),  # label: integer from 0-N
                       'train/height': _int64_feature(height), 
                       'train/width': _int64_feature(width)}
        # create example protocol buffer
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
        # serialize protocol buffer to string
        tfrecord_writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    tfrecord_writer.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason for your error is that `tf.train.BytesList(value)` expects a *list* of bytes objects. If you only pass a bytes object as `value`, like this:

```
tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=b'GAME'))
```

then it will interpret it as a list, with the values of the bytes in it; so `b'GAME'` will be interpreted as `[71, 65, 77, 69]`, and then it will complain that `71` is an `int` and not a `bytes` object.

The solution is to transform your `value` in a list, so do this (in your `_bytes_feature()` function):

```
tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[b'GAME']))
```

Note the square brackets around the `bytes`. This is a list of length one. Of course, you can pass `value` instead of the hard-coded `b'GAME'`: `tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))`

Note, also, that you already do this in the `_int64_feature()` function, which works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `_bytes_feature` where you should be using `_int64_feature` at line 29.

How do I know this? It's all in the error message.

> ```
> TypeError: 71 has type int, but expected one of: bytes
> ```

You're providing an `int`, so you need to use the `int` function. I guessed that `_int64_feature` might be able to do this, since it was there.

Error messages aren't just "something went wrong" when you're a programmer. They're an invaluable tool for working out what went wrong, once you know how to read them.

Comment: But the type is 'bytes' not 'int'. Changing  it still have TypeError.